# ImageButton tint selector is not changing color based on state

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles, android-imagebutton

I want to change `ImageButton` icon color tint based on `Button` state. Its working with background for generic `Button`, but for `ImageButton` icon, its not working at all. Its still in "enabled" state even if I disable it.

```
<style name="newbutton.iconified">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/button_height</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_height</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/small_padding_start</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/small_padding_end</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/small_padding_top</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/small_padding_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/buttons_button_iconified</item>
</style>
```

buttons_button_iconified.xml

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="200"
    android:enterFadeDuration="200">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:color="@color/button_primary"
        />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:color="@color/button_primary"
        />
    <item
        android:alpha="1"
        android:color="@color/button_primary"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: change from this `android:state_enabled="false"` to `android:state_pressed="false"` and check again.

Comment: use backgroundTint

Comment: backgroundTint is changing tint of background, which is transparent. I need to change tint of Icon